# Ask a question on construction continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let E and F be disjoint closed sets of real numbers. Prove that there is a continuous function f with domain the real numbers such that {x : f(x)=0}=E and{x:f(x)=1}=F.

The textbook gives the solution. Now E ∪ F is closed so the complement of (E ∪ F ) is open. Therefore, the complement of (E ∪ F ) can be expressed as pairwise disjoint union
of open
intervals. I can understand until here.

Write $I_j = (a_j , b_j)$. Now define

[image]

I feel very confused on this solution. f(x) is defined on R, hence we need to consider E, F, and $I_j$. But the solution discusses $a_j , b_j$. The last case is $a_j \in F , b_j \in F$. If this is true, then x is in F?

Comment: Another approach to defining a similar function: define first for closed $G$ the function $d(x,G)=\inf_{g\in G}|x-g|$ then show $d(x,G)$ is continuous and $d(x,G)=0$ if and only if $x\in G.$ define $$f(x)=\frac{d(x,E)}{d(x,E)+d(x,F)}$$ This technically requires $E,F$ non-empty.

Comment: The answer should say what happens when $a_i=-\infty$ or $b_i=+\infty.$

Comment: Great. I prefer your method. But how to show f(x) that you constructed is continuous? Oh I see. Since distance function is continuous, then f(x) is from the arithmetic operations +, −, ×, and ÷ , thus preserve continuity. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, with the additional fact that $d_E(x)+d_F(x)>0$ for all $x,$ so we can actually divide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, when $a_i,b_i\in F,$ $x\notin F.$

For example, if $E=\{0\}$ and $F=\{1,2\}.$ Then one of the intervals in the complement is $(1,2).$ The intervals are the complement of $E\cup F,$ so the intervals never have points in $E$ or $F.$

The big problem in the answer is that it fails to deal with the case where $a_i=-\infty$ or $b_i=+\infty.$

There should also be a case when $a_i,b_i\in E.$

---

I prefer this answer:

Define first, for non-empty closed $G,$ the function $d_G(x)=\inf_{g\in G}|x-g|.$ Then show $d_G$ is continuous, non-negative, and $d_G(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in G.$

Then, define $$f(x)=\frac{d_E(x)}{d_E(x)+d_F(x)}$$

This argument works in any metric space.

This argument  does requires $E,F$ non-empty.

If $E=\emptyset,F\neq \emptyset$ you can define $f(x)=\frac{1}{d_F(x)+1}.$

If $E\neq \emptyset,F=\emptyset$ then $f(x)=\frac{d_E(x)}{1+d_E(x)}.$

If both are empty, you can pick $f(xj=\frac12.$

---

Proving $d_G$ is continuous:

Since $|y-g|\leq |y-x|+|x-g|$ you get:

$$d_G(y)\leq |y-x| +d_G(x).$$

Similarly:

$$d_G(x)\leq |y-x|+d_G(y)$$

Together, this means $$|d_G(x)-d_G(y)|\leq |x-y|.$$

So given $\epsilon>0$ You can choose $\delta=\epsilon.$ You actually get $d_G$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: But the question said clearly that "Let E and F be disjoint closed sets of real numbers." I think E and F cannot be both empty, right?

Comment: In your answer, if E is empty, F is not empty, then your construction f(x) cannot be 0.

Comment: No, empty sets are closed sets, and 5e empty set is disjoint from every set.

Comment: Right, when $E$ is empty, we want no $x$ where $f(x)=0,$ because $f(x)=0$ is supposed to imply $x\in E,$ and there are no elements to an empty set.

Comment: I see. Thank you. So when both are empty, then f(x) is constant = 1/2? Your writing is messy in the last sentence.

Comment: Yes, when both are empty, you just need a continuous function which is never $0$ or $1.$ A constant function is as good as any.

Comment: One final question: where do we use the condition that E and F are closed?

Comment: If $G$ isn’t closed, then $d_G(x)=0$  For some $x\notin G.$ This means $f(x)=0$ for some $x\notin E,$ and also possibly that $d_E(x)+d_F(x)=0.$